# jquery : How to wait scrollTop animation to finish before do something?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I came across many topics like this but none of that solve my issue. What I wanted for my function is when user scroll to the next page, the user had to wait the scrollTop animation to reach its target destination before doing something else. Please help me on this code.

my Jquery code is something like this:

```
if(status == 1 ) {
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#b2").offset().top},900);
    prev.style.display = "block";
    b1Slide_b('b1');
    b1Slide('b2');
    status = 2;
} else if(status == 2) {
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#b3").offset().top},900);
    b1Slide_b('b2');
    b1Slide('b3');
    status = 3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jquery's animate has a callback for when the animation is completed.
You can use this by adding a function after your duration parameter for example

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#b2").offset().top},900, function() {
  //EXECUTES WHEN ANIMATION COMPLETES
});
```

For more information check out http://api.jquery.com/animate/ and https://jsfiddle.net/Lmf78jqd/